# Rails serving files outside assets folder and public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, static-files

**Rails version:** Rails 3.2.15

**Ruby version:** ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407)

**Issue:**

> My rails app in development mode is serving files from **storage** folder which is at root level. The file format is pdf and mp4.
>
> By serving i mean if I hit the route directly Eg: http://localhost:3000/assets/file_name.pdf is not throwing error and instead is opening on the browser.
>
> I want to put these files behind authentication and hence tried putting it outside **app/assets** and **public/** folders.
>
> I'm not sure why is it able to serve any file outside those directories. Here are few of my configs for reference:
>
> `config.assets.enabled = true`
>
> `config.assets.compress = false`
>
> `config.assets.debug = true`

Please help...

Comment: What do you mean by 'serve'?

Comment: By the way, your Ruby and Rails versions are both officially unsupported now. You should probably upgrade.

Comment: @court3nay: I've updated the question. I'm hitting the url directly for pdf file using assets/file_name.pdf and it's loading the file. I was expecting an error.

Comment: @TomLord : Thanks Tom. Upgrading is in the pipeline in the long run. It's not in my control. It's a client app.

Comment: Just a side note: The Rails version you mentioned is almost three years old and it has known security issues. Rails 3.2  is not maintained anymore in general. That means you are missing important bug fixes and security updates. You might want to consider upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: @spickermann : Please read previous comments. Already addressed that point. Thanks.

Comment: @spickerman rails 3.2 still gets security patches. However 3.2.15 can easily be upgraded to 3.2.22 and in fact should be as a matter of utmost urgency!

Comment: @court3nay: I am sorry, but http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html#severe-security-issues clearly states that Rails 3.2 does not even get Severe Security Issues fixed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a symlink within the assets directory, a setting in the pipeline, a monkeypatch in asset pipelines, or more likely, or the file itself is  there's an 'assets' controller or route. Look carefully :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was some code which when you access the files from **app/assets** copied those to **lib/assets** as well. Hence, even after deleting the assets from **app/assets** it was serving a few files from **lib/assets**

> 2.2 Asset Organization
>
> Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets.

That's the official documentation for order and organization of assets.